# Overlay-navbar using npm overlay-navbar module?

Tags: reactjs, npm, module, overlay, npm-install

I am Creating a overlay-navbar using npm overlay-navbar module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/overlay-navbar
But I am getting a error:

the requested module './io5' contains conflicting star exports for the names 'iologoandroid', 'iologoangular',
'iologoapple', 'iologobitbucket', 'iologobitcoin', 'iologobuffer',
'iologochrome', 'iologoclosedcaptioning', 'iologocodepen', 'iologocss3', 'iologodesignernews', 'iologodribbble',
'iologodropbox', 'iologoeuro', 'iologofacebook', 'iologoflickr',
'iologofoursquare', 'iologogithub', 'iologogoogle', 'iologohackernews', 'iologohtml5', 'iologoinstagram',
'iologoionic', 'iologoionitron', 'iologojavascript', 'iologolinkedin',
'iologomarkdown', 'iologonosmoking', 'iologonodejs', 'iologonpm', 'iologooctocat',
'iologopinterest', 'iologoplaystation', 'iologopython', 'iologoreddit', 'iologorss', 'iologosass', 'iologoskype',
'iologoslack', 'iologosnapchat', 'iologosteam', 'iologotumblr', 'iologotux', 'iologotwitch', 'iologotwitter',
'iologousd', 'iologovimeo', 'iologovk', 'iologowhatsapp',
'iologowindows', 'iologowordpress', 'iologoxbox', 'iologoxing', 'iologoyahoo', 'iologoyen', '
iologoyoutube' with the previous requested module './io'

what can I do to resolve this issue ?

Here is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "overlay-navbar": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.3",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.65.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried reinstalling modules but it does'nt work

Comment: can you show your package.json at least?I think this issue is related to webpack 5

Comment: I had edited my question now you can see package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue is related to **react-icons** and **webpack 5**.
Someone has already posted a similar issue in react-icons github https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/issues/514

and you're using **create-react-app** version 5 which use **webpack 5** as module bundler. Nothing we can really do until **react-icons** updating their library regarding this (if you insist on using version 5).

Meanwhile, the easiest way you can downgrade your webpack to version 4 by downgrading **create-react-app**.
Try this command:
`npm i react-scripts@4`

**note: I notice too that you're using **react-router-dom ^6.2.1**, you should downgrade this too as **overlay-navbar** doesn't support that version.
Try this command:
`npm i react-router-dom@5`

Answer (score 2):

I have found a very simple but effective solution, Problem is offcourse with React Icons as there is some kind of bug in io folder, so all you need to do is

```
npm uninstall react-icons
```

then install version 3 by running

```
npm install react-icons@3
```

boom this worked in my case. Also i suggest you to do the same for react-router-dom because there is an issue with Route in it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your are concerned about using    `overlay-navbar` then there is a way of using it without degrading react Scripts and react router.
`Overlay-Nav-bar` doesn't uses any icons from io and io5 folders so follow the following steps.
-Go to node modules -> react icons folder
Then Go to `add.js` file and then comment out this line `// export * from './io5';`
Then go to `all.d.ts` file and comment out the same file.
`

```
// THIS FILE IS AUTO GENERATED
export * from './fa';
export * from './io';
// export * from './io5';
export * from './md';
export * from './ti';
export * from './go';
export * from './fi';
export * from './gi';
export * from './wi';
export * from './di';
export * from './ai';
export * from './bs';
export * from './ri';
export * from './fc';
export * from './gr';
export * from './hi';
export * from './si';
export * from './im';
export * from './bi';
export * from './cg';
export * from './vsc';
```

`

Restart Your Development server. It should work Now